# Async/Await and Entity Framework SQL Procedure UI Thread Locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, t-sql, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I've been transitioning myself from BackGroundWorker to Async/Await programming. For the most part, it's been pretty simple. However, today I'm working with Entity Framework 6 and it's not playing nice. What I have here is a Procedure that I'm executing over a whole lot of entries. I want feedback to a progress bar since this is a lengthy process made up a somewhat lengthy processes.

This is the background worker; that doesn't thread lock the UI, I was using;

```
private void ButtonMRCUpdateAll(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    cmdMRCUpdateAllExcelSheets.Enabled = false;
    cmdMRCUpdateSingleClient.Enabled = false;
    tsStatusBar.Value = 0;
    tsStatusBar.Visible = true;
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += delegate {
        DateTime YearAndMonth = new DateTime(dtpMRC.Value.Year, dtpMRC.Value.Month, 1);
        List<string> List = new List<string>();
        using (wotcDB DB = new wotcDB()) {
            var r = DB.client_main.
                Where(t => t.Active == true).
                OrderBy(t => t.CLIENTCODE).
                Select(t => t.CLIENTCODE);
            List.AddRange(r.ToArray());
        }
        bw.ReportProgress(0, List.Count);
        int PercentComplete = 0;
        foreach (var Client in List) {
            using (wotcDB DB = new wotcDB()) {
                DB.system_MRC(Client, YearAndMonth);
            }
            PercentComplete++;
            bw.ReportProgress(PercentComplete);
        }
    };
    bw.ProgressChanged += delegate (object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs ex) {
        if (ex.UserState != null) { tsStatusBar.Maximum = (int)ex.UserState; }
        tsStatusBar.Value = ex.ProgressPercentage;
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate {
        MessageBox.Show("Monthly Results and Changes - Task Complete");
        cmdMRCUpdateAllExcelSheets.Enabled = true;
        cmdMRCUpdateSingleClient.Enabled = true;
        tsStatusBar.Visible = false;
        tsStatusBar.Value = 0;
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This is the Async/Await that I'm trying to use. This thread locks the UI and I'm not sure why. I think it's the Entity Framework call since I've used foreach with other non EF functions and it's worked just fine.

```
private async void ButtonMRCUpdateAllExcelSheetsClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await ProcessEntries();
}

private async Task ProcessEntries() {
    cmdMRCUpdateAllExcelSheets.Enabled = false;
    cmdMRCUpdateSingleClient.Enabled = false;
    tsStatusBar.Value = 0;
    tsStatusBar.Visible = true;

    DateTime YearAndMonth = new DateTime(dtpMRC.Value.Year, dtpMRC.Value.Month, 1);
    List<string> List = new List<string>();
    using (wotcDB DB = new wotcDB()) {
        var r = DB.client_main.
            Where(t => t.Active == true).
            OrderBy(t => t.CLIENTCODE).
            Select(t => t.CLIENTCODE);
        List.AddRange(await r.ToArrayAsync());
    }
    tsStatusBar.Maximum = List.Count;

    foreach (var Client in List) {
        await AsyncProcessEntry(Client, YearAndMonth);
        tsStatusBar.Value += 1;
    }

    cmdMRCUpdateAllExcelSheets.Enabled = true;
    cmdMRCUpdateSingleClient.Enabled = true;
    tsStatusBar.Visible = false;
    tsStatusBar.Value = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("Monthly Results and Changes - Task Complete");
}

private Task<string> AsyncProcessEntry(string Client, DateTime? YearAndMonth) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    using (wotcDB DB = new wotcDB()) {
       DB.system_MRC(Client, YearAndMonth);
    }
    tcs.SetResult("");
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly in the Async/Await that is causing a UI thread lock?

EDIT (system_MRC);

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[system_MRC]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @CLIENTCODE AS VARCHAR(16),
    @Date AS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ~~ A whole lot of math stuff, then some inserts/updates based on if the entries exist already.

END
```

Comment: You don't need any of that code. BGW especially is obsolete. Use `.ToListAsync()` or `.ToArrayAsync()` etc to execute an EF query asynchronously, ie `var list= await r.ToListAsync();`

Comment: Another problem is that `async void` is only meant for event handlers. It can't be awaited. Use `async Task` if you want to create an asynchronous method that doesn't return any results

Comment: It's a procedure so I'm not trying to get a return. Is there a way to run a procedure asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, use `async Task`, not `async void`.

Comment: When you `await`, the *default* behaviour is to *respect sync context*, and come back via that - which for you means "on the UI thread"; does `AsyncProcessEntry` happen to do quite a bit of non-async work before it does the async thing? because if so: that's going to be happening on the UI thread. `ConfigureAwait(false)` might help, but a: the UI bits *need* to be on the UI thread, and b: if `AsyncProcessEntry` does significant non-async work, you need to move that *off* the UI thread

Comment: AsyncProcessEntry is included in my post above. All it does is open a context and run a procedure. That is all. I've edited my post with the suggested changes.

Comment: @Kayot post the code for `system_MRC`. Why not make that into an asynchronous method as well?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Since I'm using a Procedure I couldn't use .ConfigureAwait(false)

I did incorporate the suggestions from the comments to make the reader async. This is a small query so it doesn't benefit greatly from this, however I have other queries that will and I'm going to make this a part of standard operations going forward for all queries.

What I had to do to get it working correctly was wrap the procedure in an await Task.Run() and use it that way. This saved a lot of code and I managed to get back to a single function.

```
private async void ButtonMRCUpdateAllExcelSheetsClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    cmdMRCUpdateAllExcelSheets.Enabled = false;
    cmdMRCUpdateSingleClient.Enabled = false;
    tsStatusBar.Value = 0;
    tsStatusBar.Visible = true;
    DateTime YearAndMonth = new DateTime(dtpMRC.Value.Year, dtpMRC.Value.Month, 1);
    List<string> List = new List<string>();
    using (wotcDB DB = new wotcDB()) {
        var r = DB.client_main.
            Where(t => t.Active == true).
            OrderBy(t => t.CLIENTCODE).
            Select(t => t.CLIENTCODE);
        List.AddRange(await r.ToArrayAsync());
        tsStatusBar.Maximum = List.Count;
        foreach (var Client in List) {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                DB.system_MRC(Client, YearAndMonth);
            });
            tsStatusBar.Value++;
        }
    }
    cmdMRCUpdateAllExcelSheets.Enabled = true;
    cmdMRCUpdateSingleClient.Enabled = true;
    tsStatusBar.Visible = false;
    tsStatusBar.Value = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("Monthly Results and Changes - Task Complete");
}
```

Whether this is the correct way isn't clear. When using readers it definitely isn't.

Comment: There are still many problems here like using `List.AddRange` when you can use `.ToListAsync()`. Or just use the returned array in the loop instead of the list. You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` just fine in any method marked with `async` but you shouldn't need to, unless something else blocked the UI thread.  Frankly, it would be cleaner to extract the data-access code to a separate method marked `async Task` instead of putting everything in an event handler.

Comment: As for `system_MRC` just make it asynchronous as well. It doesn't matter whether you map it to a query or stored procedure. All EF execution methods have asynchronous alternatives, eg [ExecuteSqlCommandAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommandasync(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I swapped to use a string array. I do have to pull the values into an array since I'm using them to set the maximum on my progress bar and calling a .count would cost more in processing than simply storing the small list and using foreach. The link in your comment is for using raw SQL. I'm using EF specifically to keep track of changes to the database vs my code. I've tried to make DB.system_MRC asynchronous by calling await and every way gave a syntax error. I want to keep this all in the same method as it's never used again anywhere else so I'm avoiding additional methods.

Comment: then post your code in the question! What does `system_MRC` do? How is it mapped, how does it execute the mapped stored procedure? And no, you don't need to use `List.AddRange` because you don't modify the list. An array is enough.

Comment: I said I swapped to a string[]. I've added the procedure outline, the procedure was quite long so I removed the code you wouldn't need to see. It's mapped with ADO.NET Entity Data Model sub option EF Designer from data... to update I simply remove the three entries in the model and regenerate with Update Model from Database...